# Separate values from PowerShell script for azure connection strings

Tags: c#, azure, powershell, azure-devops

I am trying to get the Azure Event hub connection string by using PowerShell script (ps1 file) but it's coming with primary and secondary connection strings How Do I separate these values? I am only interested primary connection string

this the document I am using [powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.eventhub/get-azeventhubkey?view=azps-8.2.0)

> Get-AzEventHubKey -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroupName -NamespaceName MyNamespaceName -EventHubName MyEventHubName -AuthorizationRuleName MyAuthRuleName

[image]

Comment: `Get-AzEventHubKey | Select-Object -Property PrimaryConnectionString | Format-List`

Comment: (Get-AzEventHubKey -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroupName -NamespaceName MyNamespaceName -EventHubName MyEventHubName -AuthorizationRuleName MyAuthRuleName).PrimaryConnectionString

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Dai & Toni for your suggestion it helps lot to fix the issue.

#### Ways to filter specific Property of your command in PowerShell

Use **Select-Object** to ***select the specific property*** of the result.

> Get-AzEventHubKey -ResourceGroupName < Resource Group Name> -NamespaceName < Event Hub Namespace Name> -EventHubName < Event Hub Name>-AuthorizationRuleName < Authorization Rule Name> | Select-Object -Property primaryConnectionString

If you are planning using **CLI** use **`-query`** property to ***select the specific property*** of the result

```bash
 az eventhubs eventhub authorization-rule keys list --resource-group < Resource Group Name>  --namespace-name < Event Hub Namespace Name > --eventhub-name < Event Hub Name> --name < Rule Name > --query "primaryConnectionString"
```

[image]